# Find the extinction time $T$ for the solutions $\ddot{y}+a\,\text{sgn}(\dot{y})\sqrt{|\dot{y}|}(1+|\dot{y}|^{3/2})+b\,\sin(y)=0,\,y(0)>0,\,y'(0)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, finite-duration

For the differential equation with two real-valued positive parameters $\{a,\,b\}>0$:
$$\ddot{y}+a\cdot\text{sgn}(\dot{y})\sqrt{|\dot{y}|}\left(1+|\dot{y}|^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)+b\cdot\sin(y)=0,\,y(0)>0,\,\dot{y}(0)=0 \tag{Eq. 1}\label{Eq. 1}$$

I would like to know if is possible to find its extinction time $0 < T < \infty$ such their solutions become exactly $y(t)=0,\,t>T$, as a function of their parameters and initial conditions $\{a,\,b,\,y(0),\,\dot{y}(0)\}$, being in principle, $y(t)$ a real-valued scalar function.

---

**Motivation** *- not needed for finding the solution*

Recently I learned that a ordinary differential equation (ODE) require to have a point in time where is locally non-Lipschitz (LNL) in order to been able of having solution with a finite extinction time (details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4452203/909869)), which have interesting consequences in using ODEs as a tool for model reality:

- An ODE that stands solutions of finite duration cannot hold uniqueness of solutions at the same time (or at least, violates Picard-Lindelöf Theorem's conditions due the LNL singular point).
- If a solution is of finite duration, it don't going to hold time-reversal symmetry (property is commonly only attributed to entropy).
- Since traditional physics models holds uniqueness of solutions, their solutions, accurately speaking, are always never-ending in time: this means that everything have ever happen before in time could be, in principle, affecting any experiment in the present time, which is in conflict with locality and causality.

With this in mind, I am exploring how to modify the classic nonlinear pendulum with friction in order of having a finite extinction time, and I am using a LNL drag force:
$$F_d =  a\cdot\text{sgn}(\dot{y})\sqrt{|\dot{y}|}\left(1+|\dot{y}|^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) = a\cdot\text{sgn}(\dot{y})\sqrt{|\dot{y}|} + a\cdot\dot{y}|\dot{y}|  \tag{Eq. 2}\label{Eq. 2}$$
which behaves similar to the classic quadratic drag force for high speed $F_d \approx c\cdot (\dot{y})^2$, also behaves similar the classic Stokes' Law for non-zero-low-speeds $F_d \approx 2c\cdot \dot{y},\,0.2 <\dot{y}<1.2$, and makes a singular LNL point for $\dot{y}\to 0$ so finite duration solutions could arise (see details [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/712643/317057)).

---

*Issues with numerical examples:*

*If the classic nonlinear pendulum with friction equation is reviewed as example, in [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27%2B2*0.021*x%27%2B0.2*%5Csin%28x%29%3D0%2C+x%280%29%3D%5Cpi%2F2%2C+x%27%280%29%3D0) it can be seen it have decaying solutions as expected:*
$$\ddot{x}+2\cdot0.021\,\dot{x}+0.2\sin(x)=0, x(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}, \dot{x}(0)=0 \tag{Eq. 3}\label{Eq. 3}$$

*But following the analysis for [T-Symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry), under the transformation $\hat{t} \to - t$ the position and acceleration remains the same, but the velocity profile change in sign: this applied to \eqref{Eq. 3} shows it change under this transformation, so it not fulfill T-Symmetry.*

*If instead the standard drag force $F_{\text{drag}}\propto (\dot{x})^2$ is used as is shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27%2B0.021*%28x%27%29%5E2%2B0.2*%5Csin%28x%29%3D0%2C+x%280%29%3D%5Cpi%2F2%2C+x%27%280%29%3D0) for the equation:*
$$\ddot{x}+0.021(\dot{x})^2+0.2\sin(x)=0, x(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}, \dot{x}(0)=0 \tag{Eq. 4}\label{Eq. 4}$$
*their solution aren't showing the expected decay one can see on the experimental pendulums. This is commonly solve using an ansatz for the drag force $F_{\text{drag}}\propto \dot{x}|\dot{x}|$, which as can be seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27%2B0.021*x%27*%7Cx%27%7C%2B0.2*%5Csin%28x%29%3D0%2C+x%280%29%3D%5Cpi%2F2%2C+x%27%280%29%3D0) for the equation:*
$$\ddot{x}+0.021\dot{x}|\dot{x}|+0.2\sin(x)=0, x(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}, \dot{x}(0)=0 \tag{Eq. 5}\label{Eq. 5}$$
*their solution are indeed having the expected decaying behavior for a pendulum with friction.*

*Since \eqref{Eq. 4} fulfills T-Symmetry but fails to proper model the pendulum with friction, but both \eqref{Eq. 3} and \eqref{Eq. 5} don't fulfill T-Symmetry but modeled properly the amplitudes, its look like for having a decaying behavior it was required to choose a differential equation that is not fulfilling the* **time-reversal-symmetry**.

*But, since the function $f(x)=x|x|$ is locally Lipschitz (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4472977/909869)), it cannot be used for having a singular point on a finite time where uniqueness could be broken, so this ansatz wouldn't have solutions of finite duration, this is why I chose to work instead with $F_d$ which also [shows](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27%2B0.021*sgn%28x%27%29*sqrt%28%7Cx%27%7C%29*%281%2B%7Cx%27%7C%5E%283%2F2%29%29%2B0.2*%5Csin%28x%29%3D0%2C+x%280%29%3D%5Cpi%2F2%2C+x%27%280%29%3D0) to have the decaying solutions (but also without T-Symmetry):*
$$\ddot{x}+0.021\,\text{sgn}(\dot{x})\sqrt{|\dot{x}|}(1+|\dot{x}|^{\frac{3}{2}})+0.2\sin(x)=0, x(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}, \dot{x}(0)=0 \tag{Eq. 6}\label{Eq. 6}$$

---

*Analysis of the decay*

Since for some parameters $\{a,\,b\}$ the equation \eqref{Eq. 1} is having decaying solutions as can be seen for the example of \eqref{Eq. 6}, when the time is reaching the extinction time, the behavior of \eqref{Eq. 1} will be driving by:

- For the position the small-angle approximation could be used so $\sin(y)\approx y$
- For the drag force $F_d$, the quadratic term $\dot{y}|\dot{y}| \to 0$ for small speeds, so the remaining term $\text{sgn}(\dot{y})\sqrt{|\dot{y}|}$ will be only present.

With this, in the small-angles low-speeds regimen the equation will be behaving as:

$$\ddot{y}+a\cdot\text{sgn}(\dot{y})\sqrt{|\dot{y}|}+b\cdot y=0 \tag{Eq. 7}\label{Eq. 7}$$

Which, as for the previous examples without T-Symmetry, the equation [show](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%27%2B0.021*sgn%28x%27%29*sqrt%28%7Cx%27%7C%29%2B0.2*x%3D0%2C+x%280%29%3D%5Cpi%2F14%2C+x%27%280%29%3D0) its having decaying solutions:
$$\ddot{x}+0.021\,\text{sgn}(\dot{x})\sqrt{|\dot{x}|}+0.2\,x=0, x(0)=\frac{\pi}{14}, \dot{x}(0)=0 \tag{Eq. 8}\label{Eq. 8}$$

I have found the following papers under the term **sublinear damping** that shows example in physics of equations really similar to \eqref{Eq. 7} and \eqref{Eq. 8}:

- ["A note on the dynamics of an oscillator in the presence of strong friction" - H.Amann & J.I.Diaz](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0362-546X(03)00221-9)
- ["Behavior of Solutions of Second-Order Differential Equations with Sublinear Damping" - J. Karsai & J. R. Graef](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11072-005-0048-0)

So I believe they will be achieving a finite extinction time, but I have not being able to formally prove it.

---

**Added later**

I found this paper:

- ["The pendulum—Rich physics from a simple system" - Robert A. Nelson & M. G. Olsson](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.14703)

where the autors, in equation $(19)$ use a similar drag force of the form $F_d = b\ |\dot{y}| + c\ (\dot{y})^2$, so at least a description through two components doesn't look like a complete insane approach. Also on equations $(59)$ and $(60)$ they introduce a Drag Force $F_d = b\ \dot{y} + c\ \dot{y}|\dot{y}|$ for a more accurate description of the air effects on the pendulum.

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes it is possible" because you could just devise the (piecewise) solution to the DE and see where it falls apart; this is probably not what you mean. A Lyapunov strategy may yield some fruit, but it won't be much easier since you'd have to come up with an appropriate candidate. There is a decent amount of literature on Finite-Time Convergence in control theory & optimization literature, so that is probably where you'd want to start.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza thanks for commenting. I tried to study the Lyapunov approach but it looks too hard for me (like finding the answer through it will be enough for publishing paper)... It is the only possible way to figure it out?... I don't understand what you mean with the piecewise approach you mention... could you elaborate into it please?

Comment: Regarding the piecewise solution, I just mean solving the DE. For instance, the extinction time for $\dot{y}(t) = -\sqrt{y(t)}$ with initial condition $y(0) = y_0 > 0$ is $t = 2\sqrt{y_0}.$ Verify this by solving the DE around the initial condition to find ${y}(t) = (\sqrt{y_0} - 0.5\,t)^2.$ See that the solution vanishes at $t = 2\sqrt{y_0}$ at which point uniqueness fails and there are at least 2 solutions that agree with the DE after that time.